# Export Skype Contacts

Tags: skype

I would like to export my Skype contacts using this guide

[Skype: Backup and Restore Your Contacts](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2514/skype_backup_contacts/)

but I do not have an option "Advanced" under the tab "Contacts". How do I export my Skype contacts into vCards in Kubuntu 14.4?

Comment: Linux Skype app is way more limited than its Windows version (You know, Microsoft). There is, however, guide for OS X in that page, try that one.

Comment: @Michal: Doesn't work: That directory does not exist.